# How do I add a keyboard shortcut to a function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I did some research in Tkinter and found the root.bind('<Control-Key-whatever key', function).

I wanted to add this to an application I was making.

I made a button and I want it to perform a function when I click a certain key combination.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

def printFunction():
    print("Hello World")

root.bind('<Control-Key-v>', printFunction)

button = Button(root, text="click here", command=printFunction)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

So when I click the button the function should perform, and when I click Ctrl+v the function should perform. The button works fine, but the key combination does not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Isn't the "`Key`" in "`Control-Key`" an example/placeholder? Does just `Control-v` work?

Comment: Ive added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like

```
root.bind('<Control-v>', printFunction)
```

But keep in mind, this will again throw another error, because you have to pass `event` as a parameter to the function.

```
def printFunction(event=None):
    print("Hello World")
```

Why `event=None`? This is because your button is also using the same function as a `command` but without any arguments passed to it on declaration. So to nullify it, this is a workaround.

Alternatively, your could also pass something like `*args` instead of `event`:

```
def printFunction(*args):
    print("Hello World")
```

Hope you understood better.

Cheers

Comment: I also have one more question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873578/why-are-there-two-screens-created-when-i-only-want-one

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

def printFunction(event):
    print("Hello World")

button = Button(root, text="click here", command=lambda:printFunction(None))
root.bind('<Control-v>', printFunction)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

- Argument `event` is needed for the concerned function
- Event name should be converted to `<Control-v>`
- Don't forget to add `lambda` just before the function name call from
  the button in order to call without issue by any means.

Comment: Try pressing the buttons and the error would pop up.

Comment: Runs fine for me with no error.  More than one thing can be bound to a function.  I would say that if you define printFunction(*args) instead, you wouldn't have to ever use a lambda

Comment: I also have one more question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873578/why-are-there-two-screens-created-when-i-only-want-one